# Limitations of exposing Java web services using javax.xml.ws.Endpoint?

Tags: java, .net, web-services, jax-ws

I am trying to expose some Java web services so that I can interoperate from C# (see this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1703951/interoperate-between-c-and-java-using-web-services-without-a-java-ee-application/1704059)).  The proof of concept code below works great with WCF!

My question is about the use of the `javax.xml.ws.Endpoint` class to publish my service:

1. What do I forfeit by going this route instead of a full-blown application server?
2. Is this an appropriate solution for long-running service with a low volume of calls?

The following produces WSDL, is cleanly callable from .Net, and performs well.  *Why wouldn't I use it?*

```
@javax.jws.WebService
public class TestSvc { 
    @javax.jws.WebMethod()
    public String sayHello() {
        return "Hello!";
    }
}

import javax.xml.ws.Endpoint;
public class Main  {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Endpoint.publish("http://localhost:8181/Test", new TestSvc());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Often the scalability arguments (thread pools etc) are quite forceful, but you've already discounted those.

Next, reliability. Some App Servers have nice clustering capabilities, very easy to add new instances, hence enabling fault tolerance while enabling a consolidated administrative view.

Ease of administration generally is quite handy as your number of services grows.

Security infrastructures and declarative security models can be quite important.

For me, the whole Java EE programming model is worth having when your business logic becomes non-trivial. Now we could get into the whole EJB v Spring v ... debate. But the general point I want to make is that as your business logic gets more serious you need facilities such as thread management, persistence,  connection pooling, messaging, caching and scheduling; stuff you find in App Servers. Some of that comes naturally in EJB3+JPA, or Spring, some as a natural add-on in the App Servers. If you have prospects of doing serious enterprise-scale Java development it may be better to buy into a little more complextity now in order to get onto an extensible basis for the future.

Comment: I'm okay with trading off some of the features of an App Server, so long as we don't run into any gotchas with the built in stuff. What do you mean by the JEE programming model?  (I'm a C# guy-- is this Enterprise Java Beans?)

Answer (score 2):

Besides losing the benefits of an application server in general, you may lose the ability to manage and administer and test the service if you were to use an application server.

In the inter-op side, you would not be able to extract a WSDL without the java call.  If your new service executed something when it was published, you may have to design around that.  If you plan to use WCF or something similar to consume the WSDL, there are some quirks in the VS side that you have to work around when generating the service clients (the quirks don't happen every generation, but they do happen from time to time.)

A long-running service (I assume in other words you mean a service expected to run indefinitely) would just have to be managed as a process.  Depending on your design and requirements, you would have to think about starting and stopping the process, pausing it, etc.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more about those WSDL quirks?  Intermittent?  Sounds scary.  :)

Comment: Two of them to highlight:
1.  Visual Studio seems to hang often when re-generating the client from a WSDL.  The end result is frustrating and time consuming because it requires you to kill the process, dismantle your solution a little, and then put it back together.  It only takes about 10 mins (or so), but it happens often enough that you end up cringing each time you have to re-generate.  The problem surely lies within one line of code some where, but a google search will show you that lots of people have the same line of code.
2.  The client will generate a separate type ... ran out of room

Comment: Problem #2:  The client will be generated with it's own personal copy of objects from the WSDL.  If you have two services that each return the same object on the Java side, the C# side will have two separate objects packaged in different packages.  So, you will have some design to do on the C# side to rationalize how to use the same object in two different packages.

Comment: Thanks-- as long as there aren't any issues with the way we are exposing the web services, I'm okay with that. I have never seen VS 2008 hang on WSDL but will keep an eye out for it. The way we handle #2 is to use the IDE (or svcutil.exe) to generate the client classes and then integrate them into our project manually. Once the web service interface becomes stable this isn't really much work.