# Pass XML data from C# to Java?

Tags: c#, java, xml, sockets

I have two applications: one in C#, the other in Java. I need a way to transfer data from the C# application in XML format to the Java application using some kind of service.

I have only worked with sockets before, but am looking for something less proprietary for future use with other applications. What other alternatives are there?

*Please note that the extent of my knowledge with working with sockets was a simple client/server written in java.

Comment: It's hard to know exactly what you're asking here. The obvious option would be to use HTTP, for example...

Comment: Basically WSDL based communications is what is required... A previous question discusses that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1703951/interoperate-between-c-sharp-and-java-using-web-services-without-a-java-ee-appli

Comment: Here is [an example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13165533/deserialize-json-object-sent-from-android-app-to-wcf-webservice) using WCF+Json+Java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If both programs run on the same machine, you could of course also use files, but in general, this is how it goes down:

1. Create a webservice in C#, implementing a method that exposes your data.
2. Use the wsimport tool provided with the jdk, point it at the above created .wsdl file to generate java classes to use as a soap client.
3. Use generated classes to consume webservice.

Comment: This sounds like it has potential. I'll have to do more research on how to implement a web service in C# to give it a try

Answer (score 1):

(I see now you insist on XML. So forget about it)

These are completely distinct issues - it's like asking if I want to speak with you now, should we have a phone call in French or maybe mail correspondence in Mandarin. So it's:

1. Means of transferring data (S.A HTTP, or TCP, or whatever).
2. Some common structure of data.

Confusingly, both are regarded as 'protocols'.

Anyhow I'd say `protobuf` over HTTP is the most obvious and straight forward  thing to use.

Comment: The common structure is indeed XML, but it's the means of transferring that data that I need and do not understand. I need it to be compatible with both programming languages, as well as being capable of understanding XML format

Comment: What you need is called *HTTP*, and is supported by anything nowadays.